# Is immediate addressing faster than a register access?

Tags: c, assembly, addressing-mode

Like, say you have a variable `c`, which, due to optimization by the CPU, you can safely assume to be stored in a register.  Which of the following is faster?

```
c = getchar();
if( c == 033 ){
    putchar( 033 );
    …
}
```

or

```
c = getchar();
if( c == 033 ){
    putchar( c );
    …
}
```

I am guessing the first one would be faster, since it uses immediate addressing rather than a register access.  Is my assumption correct?

Comment: You should assume that the compiler will generate the same code for both, using whichever of immediate or register addressing is faster. You should not worry about it.  In this case I would write `putchar(c)` because I think the code is more readable overall that way, but reasonable people can disagree.  It would also be more readable if you didn't use octal and didn't put spaces on the inside of your parentheses.

Comment: Look at the disassembly. I really wouldn't care about the difference.

Comment: I'd start up a precision benchmarker and test them.

Comment: Micro-optimizations yield micro-improvements.

Comment: Does  the cpu decide if a variable is stored in a register?

Comment: In praxis, this will make no difference. In theory, you could argue, that immediate addressing would enlarge your code (by the immediate value) and your l1-cache is a little less efficient. Combined with a loop, which will the no longer fit in a single cacheline, you might end up being much slower.

Comment: It's irrelevant, as you are doing single byte output operation, which will hurt much more than some subtlety of register usage. Ie. `putc` is really wrong example. But even theoretically, let's ignore the `putc` ... and again the calling convention will make bigger difference, if this is 32b target with pushing arguments on stack, this will hurt much more than 64b.. where the argument must end in register anyway, so your *immediate* variant will be worse. But generally most of the time the usage of register is for free = better (as long as it was not modified just recently).

Comment: And neither of your examples shows "addressing" BTW.

Comment: From the point of view of "magic numbers" the second example is better, since it does not repeat the magic number, which still only appears once.

Comment: Given the thousands (millions?) of clock cycles consumed by the call to putchar, any difference between the two is going to be negligible. Always focus on writing clear, understandable code first and only optimize if there is a problem with speed. Then, don't waste time with these tiny gains, look at your algorithms to see if they can be improved.

Comment: A single `putchar()` is normally only a few cycles; it becomes expensive only if it has to flush the buffer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Unfortunately that hasn't been true in a long time on most systems because of multithreading locking. You need to use `putchar_unlocked` if you want the old fast and efficient single threaded `putchar`.

Comment: @RossRidge: even with locking, in a single-threaded program, the time for a `putchar()` isn't going to be thousands, let alone millions, of clock cycles.  But you're right that `putchar_unlocked()` is more what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on the instruction set and an immediate vs register, the register is probably slightly slower a clock or two as you need an immediate or a load to get it into the register.  Where with an immediate it is in the instruction unless the instruction set is variable length and that may cost you instruction cycles there as well.

The putchar is going to swamp this anyway, hundreds to thousands of clock cycles vs the one or two you are trying to save here.

Some instruction sets have limits on the immediate.  So this is very instruction set dependent and then application dependent.

Answer (score 0):

This will not effect much as this is just a snippet. Rather i would say it would work better when we write putchar(c) as this is what compiler is trained to understand more .